# Joomla access denied for www-data while using mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla1.6

I have used mysql mysql_real_escape_string($somevariable) in my code developed using Joomla! api.
Everything is working perfectly except that this question is showing error.

`mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /var/www/JOOMLA/components/com_quiz/models/questions.php`

I searched on internet and got following solution:
create a `$con=mysql_connect(....);` and pass this as the 2nd parameter in `mysql_real_escape_string($somevariable,$con)` which works fine.

The thing is I am using Joomla API every where in my code.So ho can i use the default Joomla db object  `$db =& JFactory::getDBO();` for this??

Basically I want something like
`$db =& JFactory::getDBO();`
`mysql_real_escape_string($somevariable,$db)`

but it shows error:
`mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in /var/www/JOOMLA/components/com_quiz/models/questions.php on line 85`

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the Joomla database object to do your queries, why would you want to use the mysql library's escaping function? You don't need to. Follow this [Joomla wiki entry](http://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines#Constructing_SQL_queries) which shows you how to create properly escaped SQL queries using their DBO.

Answer (score 0):

Use instead $db->quote($somevariable);